# Ignoring Jackson InvalidFormatException to use @ExceptionHandler for @Valid @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, jackson

Basically, I'm trying to validate inputs from the @RequestBody of a REST controller using an @ExceptionHandler to catch MethodArgumentNotValidException constraints.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createbaseline")
public ResponseEntity<?> createBaseline(@Valid @RequestPart Baseline baseline){
  //...
  return ResponseEntity.ok("...");
}
```

Before I can do that Jackson is throwing an InvalidFormatException when it fails to parse a string to a Date, thus preventing my @ExceptionHandler from validating the remaining inputs. Here is my @ExceptionHandler method that I want to use for validating inputs.

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
protected final ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex){
  Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
  ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(error -> {
      String[] mapping = error.getDefaultMessage().split(":");
      errors.put(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
  });
  return new ResponseEntity<>(errors, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I've considered just changing the Date property of the object to a String, but I know that's against best practices. The reason why I want to use the handleMethodArgumentNotValid is because I have custom constraint annotations on fields in my objects that specify a key that I can access via MethodArgumentNotValidException.getBindingResult() like so:

```
@RequiredFieldConstraint(key = "label")
private String label;
```

The client can then use those keys to determine which input field will show an error. If I used the method below to catch the InvalidFormatException then I don't have access to those keys specified by the field annotations.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {InvalidFormatException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception e){
  //can't access annotation keys in this method body
  return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("bad");
}
```

I need to be able to validate ALL inputs sent in the @ResponseBody in order to send the appropriate error message back to the client but I'd still like to utilize deserializing the @RequestBody directly into an object. Does anyone have ideas on how to approach or work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this by implementing a custom deserializer for Dates so that it catches the InvalidFormatException but still returns a new Date() with .setTime(-1) that I can check for in my handleMethodArgumentNotValid method along with all the other inputs.